# Why isn't my UIButton Text changing when I call .setTitle? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button that changes the text of two other buttons when pressed. Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func nextDay(sender: AnyObject) {
    selectedDate = selectedDate.set("day", value: selectedDate.day + 1)!
    //update button text
    monthDayYearButton.setTitle(formatter.stringFromDate(selectedDate), forState: .Normal)
    dayOfTheWeekButton.setTitle(selectedDate.weekdayName, forState: .Normal)
}
```

However, only the dayOfTheWeekButton changes its title. The only difference I am aware between the two buttons, is that the monthDayYearButton uses Attributed Text instead of Plain Text. I used Attributed Text only to set the font to bold.

I have tried this for every button forState, including allZeros.

Don't worry about my strange NSDate operations, I installed a cocoa pod called SwiftDate.

Comment: Can you verify that 'monthDayYearButton' is not nil ? Make sure it is properly connected in the storyboard.

Comment: Just check the button IBOutlet connection in your interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use: 
`monthDayYearButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString, forState: UIControlState)`

Comment: Yup, thank you! `monthDayYearButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: formatter.stringFromDate(selectedDate), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)]), forState: .Normal)`